# Subtotal for a partition by column value

Tags: sql, db2

If I have data such as:

```
K1   K2  V3 
100  A   C
100  A   C
100  A   D
200  B   D
200  B   D
200  B   C
```

I'm partitioning my data by K1 & K2, so I can get the totals with a count:

```
count(V3) over (partition by K1, K2)
```

Which yields:

```
K1   K2  V3  Total 
100  A   C   3
100  A   C   3
100  A   D   3
200  B   D   2
200  B   E   2
```

How can I get a subtotal for the partition referencing the value in the row?  So result would be:

```
K1   K2  V3  Total Subtotal
100  A   C   3     2
100  A   C   3     2
100  A   D   3     1
200  B   D   2     1
200  B   E   2     1
```

Comment: Wow.  This is what happens when I spend too much time staring at the same problem.

Comment: ...you appear to have some errors in your data (where is the `E` coming from, the total doesn't match, you've gained/lost a row)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT 
      K1,
      K2,
      V3, 
      count(V3) over (partition by K1, K2) as Total,
      count(V3) over (partition by K1, K2, V3) as Subtotal
FROM DataTable
```